# Prove: $v_{p}(p^k!) = 1+p+p^2+...+p^{k-1}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Prove:

$v_{p}(p^k!) = 1+p+p^2+...+p^{k-1}$

Proving: *Use legendre formula*: $v_p (n!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{p^i}$. So $v_p (p^k!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^k}{p^i} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ p^{k-i} = \frac{p^k}{p-1}$ where $|p| >1$.

As for me it's not what I need. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look at an *example*, like $8! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8$ with $p=2$. Every other factor is divisible by $2$, every fourth factor is divisible by $4$, and every eighth factor is divisible by $8$, so the total amount of $2$-divisibility is $4+2+1$.  This way of looking at the problem suggests a more natural way to sum the terms is backwards: $p^{k-1} + \cdots + p + 1$.

Comment: The "Legendre formula" is obviously a more general version of your statement, so I'm not sure if it's fair to use it in a proof.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you need. The exact form of *legendre formula* is

$$
v_p(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Big\lfloor\frac n{p^i}\Big\rfloor.
$$

For $n=p^k$, the terms where $i>k$ are clearly zero. When $i\leqslant k$, $n/p^i$ is an integer, and the desired result follows.